# Mute button for my canvas animation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, html5-audio

I have a sound which i am playing in my canvas animation at a specified time in the animation sequence.

The code I am using for this is:

```
var snd = new Audio("sounds/explosion.mp3");
snd.play();
```

The sound works perfectly. I want to include a mute button to mute all sound on the page at the one time, mainly for accessibility reasons.

I am not sure how to go about this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example using JavaScript *Audio* object `muted` property to both test mute state and set mute.

```
<button id="mute">mute</button>

<script>

var snd = new Audio("sounds/explosion.mp3");
snd.play();

document.getElementById('mute').addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
  if ( snd.muted ) {
    snd.muted = false
    evt.target.innerHTML = 'mute'
  }
  else {
    snd.muted = true
    evt.target.innerHTML = 'unmute'
  }
})
</script>
```